# How do I get fluid motion for my program?

Tags: java

The program works fine, but when I hold a key or change keys the motion is not smooth. It pauses for a split second before becoming smooth. I'm still a beginner at Java so please explain in detail.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Game2015
{
   JFrame frame;
   DrawRect mainPanel;
   GridBagLayout gridbag;
   GridBagConstraints constraints;
   Data data;
   int width;
   int height;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      new Game2015();
   }

   public Game2015()
   {
      frame = new JFrame();
      width = 400;
      height = 500;

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setSize(width, height);
      frame.setResizable(false);

      data = new Data();
      mainPanel = new DrawRect(data);
      mainPanel.setFocusable(true);
      mainPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      KeyHandler keys = new KeyHandler();
      mainPanel.addKeyListener(keys);

      frame.add(mainPanel);
      frame.validate();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
         public void run()
         {
            while(true)
            {
               mainPanel.repaint();
               mainPanel.requestFocus(true);
            }
         }
      });
      thread.start();
   }

   public class KeyHandler implements KeyListener
   {
      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event)
      {

      }
      public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event)
      {

      }

      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event)
      {
         if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
         {
            if(data.getY() >= data.getSpeed())
            {
               data.setY(data.getY() - data.getSpeed());
            }
            else
            {
               data.setY(0);
            }
         }
         else if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
         {
            if(data.getY() + 95 <= height - data.getSpeed())
            {
               data.setY(data.getY() + data.getSpeed());
            }
            else
            {
               data.setY(height - 95);
            }
         }
         else if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
         {
            if(data.getX() >= data.getSpeed())
            {
               data.setX(data.getX() - data.getSpeed());
            }
            else
            {
               data.setX(0);
            }
         }
         else if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
         {
            if(data.getX() + 75 <= width - data.getSpeed())
            {
               data.setX(data.getX() + data.getSpeed());
            }
            else
            {
               data.setX(width - 75);
            }
         }
         else if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
         {
            frame.dispose();
            System.exit(0);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The code for drawing the rectangle is this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;

public class DrawRect extends JPanel
{
   BufferedImage img_player;
   File file;
   Data data;

   public DrawRect(Data newData)
   {
      data = newData;
      try
      {
         file = new File("Images\\Player.png");
         img_player = ImageIO.read(file);
      }
      catch (Exception exception)
      {

      }
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics)
   {
      super.paintComponent(graphics);
      Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) graphics;
      graphics2D.drawImage(img_player, data.getX(), data.getY(), null);
   }
}
```

and the code for the Data class is this:

```
public class Data
{
   int x, y, speed;

   public Data()
   {
      x = 0;
      y = 0;
      speed = 10;
   }

   public void setSpeed(int new_speed)
   {
      speed = new_speed;
   }

   public int getSpeed()
   {
      return speed;
   }

   public void setX(int new_x)
   {
      x = new_x;
   }

   public int getX()
   {
      return x;
   }

   public void setY(int new_y)
   {
      y = new_y;
   }

   public int getY()
   {
      return y;
   }
}
```

Comment: The usual solution is to have a timer that runs at a particular rate, and in your timer, check whether the key is pressed (you can use keyPressed, keyReleased and a boolean field for this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of have java handles events: When you first press a key, it fires an event (pressing the key), and only after a small period of time does it continue to fire events (holding the key). You can test this by printing out every time an event is fired, and it will have a small delay between the first and the rest of the events.

The way to work around this is instead of every time you press a key changing the characters position, change the characters velocity.

For example, instead of

```
if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
       if(data.getY() >= data.getSpeed())
       {
           data.setY(data.getY() - data.getSpeed());
       } else {
           data.setY(0);
       }
}   ... etc ...
```

it would be

```
if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
       data.setVelocityY(-data.getSpeed());
}   ... etc ...
```

as well as that, you'd also need to stop their velocity when they release the key. In your `keyReleased()` method, just do the same thing, but instead of setting velocity to speed, set it to 0.

```
if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
       data.setVelocityY(0);
}   ... etc ...
```

and then in your game loop and a method `update()` that handles calculations (adding velocity to position)

So

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        mainPanel.repaint();
        mainPanel.requestFocus(true);
    }
}
```

would be

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        update();
        mainPanel.repaint();
        mainPanel.requestFocus(true);
    }
}
```

where the update method would be

```
public static void update() {
    data.setY(data.getY() + data.getVelocityY());
    data.setX(data.getX() + data.getVelocityX());
}
```

You should look up basic tutorials on java games. For example, I always found [this](http://www.cokeandcode.com/info/tut2d.html) a good introductory tutorial.

Comment: Wouldn't this make it so the player never stops moving? Since the thread is continuously calling the method update, the player would keep on changing it's location and it would never stop even if the he/she lets go of the key.